# How to make facebook "Verified page"?

Tags: facebook

Hello I would like to Verify musician band page on facebook, but how I can do that? Anyone knows? Thanks Delfas.

Comment: Off topic. Ask facebook, not stackoverflow. Not a programming question either.

Comment: Guntram, there was on developers.facebook.com support redirect over here, so I have used support system "stackoverflow" to get support about facebook. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this posted on fb, maybe it helps.

Verified mark is only available for worldwide stuff such as big companies, celebrities, and such which have have potential to be faked or claimed by other people. Note that not every authentic pages are verified by Facebook and you cannot request an authentication.